# Erro mysql conect

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando ligar o mysql porém esta dando erro ao conectar. Segue o log de erro:

```
22:40:11  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
22:40:11  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:40:11  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:40:11  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:40:11  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:40:11  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
22:40:11  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

O meu `my.ini` esta assim:

```
password       = t@ke 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Comment: Será que não é bloqueio do firewall? Tenta liberar a porta 3306 no windows pro processo mysql.exe

Comment: Como faço isto ?

Comment: Faça conforme [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864914/5524514) aqui pra ver se a porta está em uso.

Comment: http://permita.me/?q=Error%3A+MySQL+shutdown+unexpectedly.+xampp  e  aqui tem um erro igual ao seu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169861/xampp-error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly